# PHP query SQL for search not working in class method

Tags: javascript, php, sql, search

I'm trying to do a simple search on database based on what user is typing, for that I'm using, javascript and PHP.

It works almost, but I'm not able to pass the character user is typing to the SQL query.

I'm sure that the variable arrives into PHP POST method at Ajax_request.php, but I'm not sure if the class in "functions.php" is well declared to make things work.

Probably is only a stupid mistake, but I'm pretty new to PHP and web development

Those are my files:

**index.php**

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />

    <title>InChiaro Ticket Admin</title>
    <meta name="description" content="The HTML5 Herald" />
    <meta name="author" content="SitePoint" />
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="result"></div>
    <input type="text" class="search-filter" id="searchcodiceCliente" name="codiceCliente" /> <!-- text AREA CODICE CLIENTE-->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            // We add the event on the class, which both inputs have
            $(".search-filter").keyup(function () {
                // Now we get the values from both inputs, using their ID's
                var codiceCliente = $("#searchcodiceCliente").val();
                //var fname = $("#searchfname").val();

                // Add both to the dataString (and URI encode the strings)

                var requestCodCliente = "get_codiceCliente_json"    
                // Check that at least one has any content
                if (codiceCliente != '')


                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "ajax_requests.php",
                        data: 'request='+ requestCodCliente +'&searchCliente='+ codiceCliente,
                        success: function (result) {
                            console.log(result);
                        }
                    });

            });
        });

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

**Ajax_request.php**

```
<?php
if (!empty($_POST)) {
    $codCliente = $_POST['searchCliente'];
    $method = $_POST['request'];

    include 'Database.php';
    include 'functions.php';

    $db = new Database();
    $functions = new Functions($db, $codCliente);


    if (method_exists($functions, $method)) {
        $data = $functions->$method();
        header('Content-Type: application/json');
        echo json_encode($data);
    }
}
?>
```

**functions.php**

```
<?php

/*function doLog($text)
{
    // open log file
    $filename = "log.txt";
    $fh = fopen($filename, "a") or die("Could not open log file.");
    fwrite($fh, date("d-m-Y, H:i")." - $text\n") or die("Could not write file!");
    fclose($fh);
}
doLog($codCliente);*/

class Functions
{
    private $db;
    private $codCliente;

    public function __construct(Database $db)
    {
        $this->db = $db;
    }
    public function setCodCliente($codCliente)
    {
        $this->codCliente = $codCliente;
    }


    public function get_codiceCliente_json()
    {
        $query = "SELECT * FROM clienti WHERE codiceCliente LIKE '%" . $this->codCliente . "%' LIMIT 15";
        $result = $this->db->dataQuery($query);
        return $result->fetchAll();
    }
}
?>
```

There is also another file called Database.php that just make a connection to the database.

Thank You in advice for the help!

UPDATE:

Log from mysql

```
2017-07-23T10:58:26.359942Z        65 Query     SELECT * FROM clienti WHERE codiceCliente LIKE '%%' LIMIT 15
```

Comment: At what point do you get an error?

Comment: I don't get a real error, the query returns me all the array, like it is wrote like this: $query = "SELECT * FROM clienti LIMIT 15"; 

So I think the problem is passing the variable $this->codClienti to the query string, or something in the class however

Comment: UPDATE:

this is log from mysql on that specific query: 
2017-07-23T10:58:26.359942Z        65 Query     SELECT * FROM clienti WHERE codiceCliente LIKE '%%' LIMIT 15

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that you didn't assign the `$codCliente` argument in your `Functions` constructor when you called this,

```
$functions = new Functions($db, $codCliente);
```

You should update your `Functions` class like this:

```
<?php

class Functions
{
    private $db;
    private $codCliente;

    public function __construct(Database $db, $codCliente)
    {
        $this->db = $db;
        $this->codCliente = $codCliente;
    }

    public function setCodCliente($codCliente)
    {
        $this->codCliente = $codCliente;
    }

    public function get_codiceCliente_json()
    {
        $query = "SELECT * FROM clienti WHERE codiceCliente LIKE '%" . $this->codCliente . "%' LIMIT 15";
        $result = $this->db->dataQuery($query);
        return $result->fetchAll();
    }
}
```

This time, when you call `get_codiceCliente_json` method, `$this->codCliente` property is not empty anymore ;)

Comment: if you find this helpful, please don't forget to upvote ;) thanks!

Answer (score 0):

there are few things I've noticed that could cause your problem...

**1.** Since part of your SQL in log looks like this `... LIKE '%%' ...` it means that your property codCliente is not properly set in your instance.

Modify this line of code ...

```
$functions = new Functions($db, $codCliente);
```

To this...

```
$functions = new Functions($db);
$functions->setCodCliente($codCliente);
```

Your constructor doesn't have defined parameter for codCliente property...

**2.** Also check *data* property in your ajax call
It looks like this now...

```
// ...
data: 'request='+ requestCodCliente +'&searchCliente='+ codiceCliente,
// ...
```

Data field can accept array/object as a value, so if you want be sure that your parameters are sent and received properly, change it to something like this...

```
// ...
data: {
    request: requestCodCliente,
    searchCliente: codiceCliente
},
// ...
```

I hope this will help :)

Comment: Hi, thank you for the help, but still having same issue.

Edited as you said, but same error in SQL log

Comment: Well, then you need to make sure that all parameters are properly passed to your php script, try to var_dump($_POST); somehere in your php code and check if that parameter is set.